# I'm trying to push data on firebase database but I'm getting this error 'Cannot read property "push" ', can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong?

Tags: javascript, firebase, web, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication

1st image shows the error I'm facing
[error- Cannot read property 'push' of undefined of script.js at line 186](https://i.stack.imgur.com/47u2z.jpg)

2nd image shows my code
[Code where I'm getting error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aWwfi.jpg)

Comment: Please don't post screenshots of your code, or other textual content. Instead post the actual text, and use the formatting tools of Stack Overflow to mark it up.

Answer (score 0):

This is a code trace error, you are invoking the function before the variable is defined. all references and global properties should be moved to the top of your script so they are defined within the script.

you will find on line 178 you are invoking the method which means that line 182 hasn't been executed yet.

Comment: I did as you said, but it is still showing the same error while on doing console.log I'm getting the desired values. It's not only pushing the data to my firebase database.

Comment: then it's most likely firestore() isn't initiated to return a reference then. this will require further debugging